# Good data structure for efficient insert/querying on arbitrary properties

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm working on a project where Arrays are the default data structure for everything, and every query is a linear search in the form of:

- Need a customer with a particular name? `customer.Find(x => x.Name == name)`
- Need a customer with a particular unique id? `customer.Find(x => x.Id == id)`
- Need a customer of a particular type and age? `customer.Find(x => x is PreferredCustomer && x.Age >= age)`
- Need a customer of a particular name and age? `customer.Find(x => x.Name == name && x.Age == age)`

In almost all instances, the criteria for lookups is well-defined. For example, we only search for customers by one or more of the properties Id, Type, Name, or Age. We rarely search by anything else.

**Is a good data structure to support arbitrary queries of these types with lookup better than O(n)? Any out-of-the-box implementations for .NET?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For in memory, you have a few options.

Most options will be O(n).  That being said, Dictionary lookups can approach O(1).

One option is to store your customers in multiple Dictionaries, each with a key set to the Name, Id, and Age.  If you use the same object references in the dictionaries, you can make any single lookup O(1), without a huge amount of overhead.

Granted, this becomes less practical as your criteria count rises, but with 3, it's not too bad.

If you want more flexibility, then a database is an appropriate option.  Many databases have the option of working as a completely in-memory database, including SQLite, which would allow arbitrary queries at much better than O(n) speed.

Comment: Problem with multiple dictionaries is that they don't support composite lookups: an age Dictionary<int, List<Customer>> returns a range of customers for a given age in constant time, but what if I also want to search by name too? I'm right back to linear search.

Comment: If you combine the results (via ANDing/ORing) I'd think you'd get better than linear.

Comment: @Juliet: You're back to linear search, but in a very restricted space.  Each additional search is restricted to just the valid elements from the first, so the search space is much smaller.  The second search is O(n), but N becomes very small.  That being said, the other option is still to use an in-memory DB, which provides you fast querying with arbitrary criteria...

Comment: @Juliet assuming `IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<Customer>> AgeIndex` and `IDictionary<String, IEnumerable<Customer>> NameIndex`, you get better than linear time by using `var results = AgeIndex[age].Intersect(NameIndex[name])`.  It's O(m) where m is the sum of the size of the two result sets, but without indexing on ALL possible search criteria (e.g., `IDictionary<AgeNamePair, IEnumerable<Customer>> AgeNameIndex`), you can't do much better.  Class time/space tradeoff.

Comment: @Dathan: results of `AgeIndex[age].Insersect(NameIndex[Name])` is not better than a linear search`. Consider I have a few guys named Steve with ages 20, 21, 22, 23, and 25. When I search for 20 year olds, I get back the name Steve -- so we pass it to the name index and I get back 5 Steve's who all have different ages, or I get back a list of 20 year olds who all have different names. So we're back to a linear search.

Comment: @Juliet: Take your case.  Say you have 1000 customers, and 5 "Steve"s, and 150 twenty year olds.  You do AgeIndex[age], which returns the 150 twenty year olds, and intersect that with NameIndex[Name], which returns the 5 steves.  Now, you're down to one intersection between a 20 element collection and a 5 element collection.  It's basically linear at that point, but you're dealing with a very small set (150+5) vs. 1000...  Also, intersect uses a set internally, so it's not a "linear" search in the same fashion.  Profile this, it's MUCH faster than linear, especially with real data.

Comment: @Reed: ok, that makes sense :) Is there a good generic solution which doesn't require making and populating dictionaries for every type I want to index? Additionally, is there a good solution that supports range searches like "age >= 20"?

Comment: +1, +answer: I was skeptical at first, thought I would need to reach out to an exotic data structure like a kd-tree, but this really worked and helped to improve wicked slow spots 5x. With a little more optimization, I think I can squeeze out a lot more speed -- in the mean time, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you put your data into several dictionaries? One dictionary maps name to the data, another maps age, etc.

Comment: For a start its not a very generic solution. We have these types of searches on more than just customers, and it would be a little insane to create a 1000s of dictionaries for the 100s of collection types we regularly search. Second, multiple dictionaries don't support searches on composite keys in reasonable time, for example I can't search for people with a given name AND age without a linear search through one of my dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

I assume all the arrays are of `IEnumerable`?

How about using LINQ to objects?

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Linq-Objects-Collections-Arrays.aspx

Then you can write query like LINQ syntax to get results from your arrays.

Comment: What does that have to do with data structure?

Comment: Not a structure but if he is trying to query these arrays and does not want to spin his wheels trying to find the perfect design, just do LINQ against your arrays and call it a day.